# IR Remote Not working with Raspberry Pi A+

Tags: remote

I am using OpenElec and XBMC on Raspberry Pi A+.
I have an [IR Remote and Receiver](http://www.ebay.in/itm/111599418813) that works out of the box on B+

But on my A+, it does not work when I connect the receiver directly to the single USB Port Or through a USB Hub.

it at least gets detected when I connect it directly. Output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 1d57:ad02 Xenta SE340D PC Remote Control
```

But when I connect it through a USB Hub it does not even get detected.

[This](http://openelec.tv/forum/134-usage/71512-usb-device-not-recognized-when-connected-via-hub) thread tells that it could be the USB port that is the problem, But I have 2 problems:

1. The Reciever works when i connect it to the USB Hub on a B+. The problem is only with A+
2. Though it gets detected when connected directly, it does not work on the XBMC. I am using the Same SD Card on both the devices.

Steps to debug this will be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is related and maybe the answer is a bit late but I give my 2 cents anyway since it might help others.

I noticed my Raspberry Pi 4 would not start when *only* the 1d57:ad02 Xenta SE340D PC Remote Control was connected. It just would not boot from SD or USB and would start the Net install.
It worked fine when another USB keyboard was detected or the Xenta was disconnected, and connected later.

The following solved this problem:

```
# rpi-eeprom-config -e
[all]
BOOT_UART=0
WAKE_ON_GPIO=1
POWER_OFF_ON_HALT=1
BOOT_ORDER=0xe14
NET_INSTALL_ENABLED=0
USB_MSD_EXCLUDE_VID_PID=1d57ad02
```

Hope this also solves your problem with the Xenta remote.